# ng-include throws [$parse:syntax] error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am trying to give `ng-include="'http://www.myxyzsite.com/assets/view/partial.html'"`.but it gaves error like

> Syntax Error: Token ':' not a primary expression at column 5 of the
>   expression [http://www.myxyzsite.com/assets/view/partial.html]
>   starting at
>   [http://www.myxyzsite.com/assets/view/partial.html].

Is it possible to use `ng-include` with absolute path?

Anybody know, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: remove the single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$templateCache` object to place your live data into it and use `ng-include` after

```
// read page using get
$http.get('link-to-page', {cache:$templateCache});
```

And you can iclude this data after using `ng-include` directive

```
ng:include src="link-to-page"></ng:include>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include references into `ng-include` as it is not built-in with Angular.

But you could create your own directive that can do this. All what you should do is send off an `http request` to the provided `url` (assuming the server that the url references is implementing **CORS**)

You can make a service and use it within your `controller` to get the content once on initialization.

**Update:**

Include Cross Domains

By default you cannot include cross domains files, however it is possible to include files from other domains.

Add a whitelist of legal files and/or domains in the `config` function of your web application:

```
<body ng-app="yourApp">

<div ng-include="'http://www.website.no/angular_include.asp'"></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('yourApp', [])
app.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'http://www.website.no/**'
    ]);
});
</script>

</body>
```

[Please, read this article.](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Please Avoid "http://www.myxyzsite.com/assets/view/" from your url   just  put partial.html   only  and run it and if it is not work then go to console and go to network section then in the  left side you can see all resources(pages) including "partial.html" and select that resource and right side you can see the requested URL link  then you can see the path  and adjust  your URL in code according to this.